# AWS API routes returning 500

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

I've recently deployed my Laravel API to AWS ElasticBeanStalk.

I wanted to test that the API was running, so I made a simple route to just return a message. Locally, it works fine:

http://my-api.localhost/

**Output**: `Welcome`

But on AWS, I get:

http://my-api.elasticbeanstalk.com/

**Output**: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` (Output twice)

It's a 500 error without much other helpful information.

I turned on debug mode and got:

```
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
```

Looked up this error and found [this](http://laravel.io/forum/06-09-2015-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid), which said to change my `config\app.php` cipher to :

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

But it was already that value.

Then it said to ensure that the .env `APP_KEY` is 32 bits, which mine is.

The request headers look similar between the localhost and aws app. There are differences, but none that I think would return a 500. I SSH'ed into the AWS EC2 to verify that the routing is the same.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router) {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'Welcome';
    });
```

---

```
class EncryptionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
Encryption Service Provider:

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('encrypter', function ($app) {
            $config = $app->make('config')->get('app');

            $key = $config['key'];

            $cipher = $config['cipher'];

            if (Encrypter::supported($key, $cipher)) {
                return new Encrypter($key, $cipher);
            } elseif (McryptEncrypter::supported($key, $cipher)) {
                return new McryptEncrypter($key, $cipher);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException('No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: There should be an error log on your server. I would look for that instead of trying to guess what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, forgot to add ENV vars to AWS app instance.

1) Go to app->configuration->software configuration

2) Add the env vars in your local `.env` and specify the unique values for Production

3) Verify ENV vars are registered on EC2 by SSH'ing into server, then `cd /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support` and run `cat envvars`. The ENV vars should be listed.

4) Then execute the envvars with `source envvars`

5) Output ENV vars to verify that they're set within the application: `echo env $APP_KEY` will spit out the ENV that you have set